# bluetooth keyboard override

Tags: ios, bluetooth

Is there a way to force up a software keyboard when the user has a iOS bluetooth keyboard device installed?

Or, to that end, is it possible in code to disable a specific bluetooth device?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not from within the application's code, if you're planning on getting into the app store.  Apple expressly does not provide methods to show or hide keyboard, instead pushing you to use `becomeFirstResponder` and `resignFirstResponder`.

You may be able to do this through some non-AppStore-friendly methods, but somehow I don't think that's the answer you're looking for.

(Note - you could make a fake, Apple-looking keyboard when the real one is hidden, and check if the real one is hidden based on whether a view is visible, but if Apple notices you doing this, you'll get denied.)

Comment: Actually, knowing the non-AppleStore-friendly calls would be helpful.  We produce the bluetooth device and should be allowed to control it, will be requesting an exception.

Comment: In this case, you may want to present the bluetooth device as something other than a keyboard, so that the iPad doesn't believe one is present.  I would talk to Apple about feasibility before writing a single line of code, though; they already have their own mechanisms in place for developing alternate input devices (such as braille readers)

Answer (score 2):

In most (maybe all?) iOS apps with which I have used Apple's bluetooth keyboard, pressing the eject key (located in the top right corner) will bring up the soft keyboard on the screen. Maybe that little factoid could help you in some way.

Comment: I've been searching around for what it feels like.. DAYS trying to find away to force show/hide keyboard when a Hardware input is present. I am using delphi which makes searching around a bit more tedious and this ^^ I believe is my solution! thanks !